# column-count with media query

Tags: css, media-queries, column-count

I am trying to get a grid of 8 images to fill the full width of the page, using column-count & media queries, but with specifying 5 or 6 columns there is a empty column on the right.

This also occurs:

When using 9 or 10 images, 6 columns doesn't work
When using 11 images, 5 columns doesn't work

Any clues appreciated, thanks

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;
    font-size: 23px;
}

html{
    background-color: grey;
}

.imgcontainer {
 line-height:0;
    column-gap:0px; 
    column-width: 100px;
    background:rgba(0, 50, 150, 0.3);
}

.myimg {
 width: 100% !important;
   height: auto !important;
   background:white;
}

.txt{
 position: absolute;
 padding: 15px;
}

#textid1 {
 background: pink;
      display:none;
}

#textid2 {
 background: yellow;
      display:none;
}

#textid3 {
 background: cyan;
      display:none;
}

#textid4 {
 background: grey;
      display:none;
}

#textid5 {
 background: red;
     display:none;
}

#textid6 {
 background: green;
     display:none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
    .imgcontainer {
        column-count: 6;
    }/**/
    #textid1 {
     display:none;
    }
    #textid2 {
     display:none;
    }
    #textid3 {
     display:none;
    }  
    #textid4 {
     display:none;
    }
    #textid5 {
     display:none;
    }
    #textid6 {
     display:block;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    .imgcontainer {
        column-count: 5;
    }/**/
    #textid1 {
     display:none;
    }
    #textid2 {
     display:none;
    }
    #textid3 {
     display:none;
    }  
    #textid4 {
     display:none;
    }
    #textid5 {
     display:block;
    }
    #textid6 {
     display:none;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    .imgcontainer {
        column-count: 4;
    }/**/
    #textid1 {
     display:none;
    }
    #textid2 {
     display:none;
    }
    #textid3 {
     display:none;
    }  
    #textid4 {
     display:block;
    }
    #textid5 {
     display:none;
    }
    #textid6 {
     display:none;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    .imgcontainer {
        column-count: 3;
    } 
    
    #textid1 {
     display:none;
    }
    #textid2 {
     display:none;
    }
    #textid3 {
     display:block;
    }  
    #textid4 {
     display:none;
    }
    #textid5 {
     display:none;
    }
    #textid6 {
     display:none;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .imgcontainer {
        column-count: 2;
    }
    
    
    #textid1 {
     display:none;
    }
    #textid2 {
     display:block;
    }
    #textid3 {
     display:none;
    }  
    #textid4 {
     display:none;
    }
    #textid5 {
     display:none;
    }
    #textid6 {
     display:none;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .imgcontainer {
        column-count: 1;
    }
    
    #textid1 {
     display:block;
    }
    #textid2 {
     display:none;
    }
    #textid3 {
     display:none;
    }  
    #textid4 {
     display:none;
    }
    #textid5 {
     display:none;
    }
    #textid6 {
     display:none;
    }
}
```

```html
    <div id="wrapper">
     <div id="textid1" class="txt">1 column</div>
  <div id="textid2" class="txt">2 columns</div>
  <div id="textid3" class="txt">3 columns</div>
  <div id="textid4" class="txt">4 columns</div>
  <div id="textid5" class="txt">5 columns</div>
  <div id="textid6" class="txt">6 columns</div>
        <div id="container">
   <div id="contentwide">
    <div class="imgcontainer">
     <img class="myimg" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2f/Google_2015_logo.svg/440px-Google_2015_logo.svg.png"/>
     <img class="myimg"  src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2f/Google_2015_logo.svg/440px-Google_2015_logo.svg.png"/>
     <img class="myimg"  src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2f/Google_2015_logo.svg/440px-Google_2015_logo.svg.png"/>
     <img class="myimg"  src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2f/Google_2015_logo.svg/440px-Google_2015_logo.svg.png"/>
     <img class="myimg"  src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2f/Google_2015_logo.svg/440px-Google_2015_logo.svg.png"/>
     <img class="myimg"  src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2f/Google_2015_logo.svg/440px-Google_2015_logo.svg.png"/>
     <img class="myimg"  src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2f/Google_2015_logo.svg/440px-Google_2015_logo.svg.png"/>
     <img class="myimg"  src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2f/Google_2015_logo.svg/440px-Google_2015_logo.svg.png"/>
     </div>  
   </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: Ignore the _column-width:100px;_ line, that shouldn't be in there

Comment: Check this: https://www.sitepoint.com/using-modern-css-to-build-a-responsive-image-grid/